# Find the minimal tank capacity to be able to travel from any city to any other

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dynamic-programming, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs

There are $n$ cities in the country. The car can go from any city $u$ to city $v$, On this road it spends $w_{u,v} > 0$ fuel. At the same $w_{u,v}$ can differ from $w_{v, u}$. The task is to find the minimal tank capacity to be able to travel from any city to any other (possibly with refuels) in $O(n^2\log n)$.

Comment: What do you mean by *refuels*?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Fuel can be added to the tank in some intermediate city. For example, the car travels from $A$ to $C$. It is possible to add fuel in the $B$.

Comment: In that case, the answer is simply $\max(w_{u,v})$. This is an $O(n^2)$ algorithm.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus No, why? For example, the car can go from $A$ to $B$ it costs $1$ fuel, from $A$ to $C$ - $6$ and from $B$ to $C$ - 3. He can manage to go all the cities with $1+3$ fuel by traveling from $A$ first $B$  then $C$. Actually, I am not sure wheater the car then after $C$ should be able to drive back to $A$ or $B$. If so than it is fully connected graph. In this case maybe you are right.

Comment: You simply refuel as you go. At each city fill the tank enough to last until the next city. The airline industry works this way.

Comment: It seems like you are not completely sure about the details of the question. This makes it extremely hard to answer.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It seems to me I understand what the problem wants. We should find the minimum tank capacity that is the minimum maximum $w_{u,v}$ that will allow us to travel from every city to every other.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I think, the solution must be the maximum $w_{u,v}$ in the minimum spanning tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution may be to compute the all pair shortest path matrix and then select the largest value in the matrix.

As long as `|E|<<|V|^2` or the graph is not dense, your complexity constraint should be satisifed.

[Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) does it in `O(|V|^2 log |V|+|V||E|)`.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265454/11148084) for a better understanding of time complexity in case of Jhonson's Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

We first sort all edges according to their costs from small to large. Say the sorted edges are $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_{n(n-1)}$, and the corresponding costs are $w_1\le w_2\le\cdots\le w_{n(n-1)}$. Then we find the minimal $i$ such that the graph is strongly connected only with the edges $e_1,\ldots,e_i$. Now $w_i$ is the minimal tank capacity we want.

Sorting costs $O(n^2\log n)$ time. To find the minimal $i$, we can use the bisection method. We first test whether the graph is strongly connected with the edges $e_1,\ldots,e_{n(n-1)/2}$. If yes, we then test the connectivity with the edges $e_1,\ldots,e_{\lceil n(n-1)/4\rceil}$, otherwise we test the connectivity with the edges $e_1,\ldots,e_{\lceil3n(n-1)/4\rceil}$, and so on. The running time to find the minimal $i$ is also $O(n^2\log n)$. So the total running time of this algorithm is $O(n^2\log n)$.